# Mongoose Model.update not working in my code

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, backend

I want to update some of the course properties with the given id. 
This is my code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    author: String,
    tags: [String],
    date: Date,
    isPublished: Boolean,
    price: Number
});

const Course = mongoose.model('Course', courseSchema);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mongo-exercises');

async function updateCourse(id) {
     const result = await Course.update({_id: id}, {
        $set: {
            author: 'New', 
            isPublished: false
        }
    });

console.log(result);
}

updateCourse('5a68fde3f09ad7646ddec17e');
```

On console I get `{ok: 1, nModified: 0, n: 0}`.

I´ve tried updating the element with this other way, but it doesnt works. For this piece of code i dont get the result, no response:

```
const course = await Course.findById(id);
  if(!course) return; 

  course.isPublished = true; 
  course.author = 'Another Author';

  const result = await course.save();
  console.log(result);
```

When i try to update using the findByIdAndUpdate with this other code, the result is null in console:

```
 async function updateCourse(id) {
    const course = await Course.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {
    $set: {
        author: 'Billy',
        isPublished: false
    }
 });

   console.log(course);

 }
updateCourse('5a68fde3f09ad7646ddec17e');
```

The database im working with has:

```
 { _id: 5a68fdd7bee8ea64649c2777,
   name: 'Node.js Course',
   author: 'Sam',
   isPublished: true,
   price: 20 },
 { _id: 5a68fde3f09ad7646ddec17e,
   name: 'ASP.NET MVC Course',
   author: 'Mosh',
   isPublished: true,
   price: 15 },
 { _id: 5a6900fff467be65019a9001,
   name: 'Angular Course',
   author: 'Mosh',
   isPublished: true,
   price: 15 },
 { _id: 5a68fe2142ae6a6482c4c9cb,
   name: 'Node.js Course by Jack',
   author: 'Jack',
   isPublished: true,
   price: 12 }
```

The course doesn't update. Where is the error? 
Note that if i want to create new documents, it does it with no problem.

Comment: Is `author` and `isPublished` already the same value you are trying to set maybe?

Comment: Hi. isPublished has the same value, but author is different. Ive tried with the other options for updating , for example by finding the element by its id and then updating it, but it doesnt works.

Comment: You are trying to update with same hard-coded value, so mongodb finds that the old and new record are same hence `nModified` field is set zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`update({_id: id},...)` specifies `_id` expecting the `_id` type in the document as `ObjectID`.

`update()`, and `findById()`, do not find `_id`, and return `null`, because the `_id` type is, probably, String in your collection/document, - check with Compass.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issues in the code and here the query and syntax are correct, according to the [MongoDB update doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/).

> The update() method returns a WriteResult object that contains the
>   status of the operation. Upon success, the WriteResult object contains
>   the number of documents that matched the query condition, the number
>   of documents inserted by the update, and the number of documents
>   modified.

Here no documents have been modified and the only reason is, you are setting the same data to update in the query.

Comment: i added the element i want to update, it has different values.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
isPublished: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
}
```

instead of

```
isPublished: Boolean
```

Comment: didnt work, the same result. im thinking that maybe is a problem of mongoose or mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

The return `{ok: 1, nModified: 0, n: 0}` says that the operation was successful but couldn't find, nor update any entry, so that means it's not even matching.

I'm not entirely sure, but I think mongoose only finds ID by `ObjectId` and not by `string`.

So you should get the desired outcome by converting it, like that:

```
const result = await Course.update({ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) }, { 
    $set: { author: 'New', isPublished: false }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add `_id:String` in your schema

```
const courseSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
  name:String,
  _id:String,
  author:String,
  tags: [String],
  date: Date,
  isPublished: Boolean,
  price: Number
});
```

And replace your promise with this:

```
async function updateCourse(id) {
  const result = await Course.update({ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) }, { 
    $set: { author: 'New Author', isPublished: false }
  });
```

I encountered the same problem in mosh node.js course and this solution worked for me! :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue with .***update()*** to I changed it to .***updateOne()*** and it worked perfectly